# Can a number type variable hold null value in Typescript without any potential problems?

Tags: typescript, types

I am new to Typescript.
I came across a scenario where, my backend API may receive a null value in some cases. I intend to keep the variable type as "number" in the API code. Can this create any problem in hidden cases or it is good to go. If there is better way to deal with this, kindly let me know the snippet. Thank you in advance :)

```
const var1:number = null;    // here var1 can be number or a null

function test(param1:number){
  console.log(param1);
}

test(var1);
```

prints null but gives error as

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

Comment: You say that your API may receive a null value. Is this the *intended* functionality, or something that may only occur due to misuse? If it is intended and you have a way to handle it, you can do this to allow null/undefined values `var1: number = param1!`

Comment: Guess what would happen with `var1.toFixed(2)` when `var1 = null`. That should probably answer your question.

Comment: I think we need more code for this to be a [mre]; it depends strongly on what you will do with the value and what should happen if it's null.  Ideally you'd just mark it as `var1: number | null = param1` (Is `var1` a variable or a property of a class?  Might be a syntax error).  Could you [edit] the question to provide a self-contained code example that demonstrates your issue when pasted into an IDE?

Comment: @Stitt , Yes It is intended functionality. I don't want to remove null.

Comment: What @VLAZ  has mentioned is the anxiety I was having.

Comment: Hi @jcalz , the solution you gave is working safely :) 
Thanks a lot all you guys for your time.

Answer (score 1):

After testing various scenarios,
the [comment by @jcalz](/posts/comments/133001444) helped to pass all test cases, where if we add type as number or null.

```typescript
const var1: number | null = null;
    
function test(param1:number | null){
   console.log(param1);
}
    
test(var1);
```